# IntelliJ and Visual Studio select and rename a variable in multiple places by a shortcut behavior as 'Ctrl+D' in Sublime?

Tags: visual-studio, sublimetext2, pycharm

Because of the lack Intellisense in Sublime, I prefer to using Visual Studio to code C# and Pycharm to Python.

`ctrl + d` in Sublime can select mutiple same word in text. So I can alter the selections on same time. It is convenient to alter the name of same variable in a function. How can I do that in my other editors?

Comment: Don't have VS on this machine so this is from memory, but mark the variable and try `CTRL + .`

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson `CTRL + .` can mark but can't alter.

Comment: Ah, too used to Resharper shortcuts to remember correctly :) Once you marked the variable with `CTRL + .`, `F2` should invoke rename. `Ctrl+R CTRL+R` should also do something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ctrl-D multiple selection tool is one of its greatest features of Sublime Text 2 and is sorely lacking in other editors and IDEs.

Visual Studio doesn't have it built-in but there's a [MultiEditing plug-in](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2beb9705-b568-45d1-8550-751e181e3aef) for it.

IntelliJ, which PyCharm is based on, doesn't have it either but it's apparently being planned for a release that should be out soon. See this [blog comment](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/phpstorm-7-early-access-program-started/#comment-2532) (and the link in it) for more.

Meanwhile, you can use the rename refactoring tool in Resharper (for Visual Studio) or in PyCharm. It's not the same as multiple selections but is very useful functionality in its own right.

Comment: MultiEditing explicitly says "What isn't supported: Multiple selections"

Comment: Note as of now PyCharm and IntelliJ have added this feature.

Answer (score 0):

A nother IDE that does support it is Webstorme - `alt`+`j`.  you can read the stackOverflow discussion about it here : [How can I select next occurrence in IDEA editors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23304855/sublime-ctrld-equivalents-in-phpstorm)

I just tested it on Webstorme10, and it works perfectly, just like in Sublime.

Answer (score -1):

Try `ctrl + h`. It is the standard shortcut in many editors for replacing text.

Comment: `ctrl + h` just call `find and replace function` in many editors.`ctrl + d` in Sublime is much more efficient and convenient.

Comment: What do you mean by `convenient`?

Comment: If `ctrl + d` on word `request`,it select current `request` and next `request`.One more `ctrl + d`,One more selected `request`.And you can alter all of them at same time.So I say it is convenient to alter the name of same variable in a function.

Comment: So you want to replace the word only inside a function? In Visual Studio simply select the function and press `ctrl+h` - it will replace only inside selected text. Also explore other Find options in the Find and Replace window.