# How can I select next occurrence in IDEA editors

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, phpstorm, webstorm

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> performs the `find_under_expand` command in sublime. This basically searched for the next occurrence of the already selected text and selected it, so when I edit, it's edited on both places at the same time. I'm currently trying to move to IDEA editors (such as WebStorm, PHPStorm, PyCharm, etc) but didn't find something like this command in this IDE yet.

Comment: This post is used as an example for [this meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315268/should-i-remove-an-ide-tag-when-the-question-asks-about-feature-comparisons)

Answer (score 254, accepted):

I believe they recently added this to the latest IntelliJ release, and I would assume PhpStorm as well. As the bindings are system specific, take a look at http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/03/working-with-multiple-selection-in-phpstorm-8-eap/. Looks like that version is available through EAP, so don't know when they will release it for general consumption (or if they have already).

#### DEFAULT SHORTCUTS

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> on Windows and Linux, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> on Mac OS X

Comment: AFAIK ETA on 8.0 version is the end of June/beginning of July.

Comment: Taken from provided link, `Alt+J` on `Windows`, `Ctrl-G` on `Mac OS X`

Comment: Yes! `Alt+J` will select/unselect the next occurrence, on Windows.

Comment: If ALT+J selects the next occurrance. How can I automatically select *all* occurrances?

Comment: @anddero `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+J` or `Ctrl-Cmd-G`

Answer (score 21):

On Mac OS X, you can select the next occurrence with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

Comment: This isn't the "Go to line" command? http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/PhpStorm_ReferenceCard.pdf

Comment: @cvsguimaraes command+G = go to next occurrence, command+ctrl+g =  go to previous, and ctrl+G = also select next occurrence (works for me at least).

Comment: What's the added value of your answer compared to Skuroda's answer posted before your ?

Answer (score 9):

Currently its mapped with

for selection, <kbd>Alt + J</kbd>

for unselection, <kbd>Alt + Shift + J</kbd>

but if you're familiar with sublime shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd>

Jetbrains give you an option to change settings,

**Settings -> Keymap -> Editor Actions**

search for multiple selection, find <kbd>Alt + J</kbd> 
then right click -> select change **keyboard shortcuts**

set shortcuts you want as like sublime, <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd>

[Here is the Docs](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2014/09/feature-spotlight-multiple-selections-in-pycharm/)

Answer (score 8):

In the settings window, search for ”Add Selection for Next Occurence” (PhpStorm 8.0.1)

On mac the default is ctrl+G, but you can change it to ctrl+D (or cmd+D on mac)

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

**On Windows**

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> - Multiple Select

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> - Unselect Multiple Select

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is refactor it at all the place in the file at once. 
So in MAC machine the handy shortcut for it is **shift + F6** (you may have have to use fn key before F6).
Click on the text you want to change and then press **shift + F6**. It will highlight the text and then your change at all the place in the file. :)

It will do the job same as sublime ctrl + D

Answer (score 1):

PhpStorm has a "Select Word at Caret", Ctl+W and Ctl+Shift+W respectively (you can check your keys by searching under Preferences > Keymap).

Detail here:
http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html#d617165e275

Not entirely sure if it's the same as you mentioned, but it's mighty handy!

Comment: Yeah it's not what OP asked for, but thanks to your link, I can find the shortcut for this "Select Word at Caret" under Mac. I'm a newbie with PHPStorm :D

Answer (score 0):

Today, another option is to simply use the Sublime Key Mappings so that you don't have to learn a new set/rewire your muscle memory.

**File -> Settings -> Keymap**

Select one of the presets (VS Code, Sublime, Eclipse, etc.), or select Plugins & install a new set of Keymappings.